# Number of prime exponents for Generalized Mersenne Primes

Tags: probability, number-theory, prime-numbers

Please help me on the following scenario(s):

Estimate the number of primes $p$ less than or equal to $x$ such that there is a prime of the form ${(a+1)}^p$ $-$ $a^p$ for all $a$ < $50$?

What is the probability that for a prime $p$ the size of $x$, there is a prime of the form ${(a+1)}^p$ $-$ $a^p$ where $a$ < $50$.

I am unsure of the distribution of these primes, not how many there are (although conjectured infinitely many).

Thanks if someone could figure this out.

Comment: Do you want an estimate for each value of  $a$ or do you want them to be prime at the same time?

Comment: If the  former, then I'd guess it should be roughly $\log \log x$.

Comment: All the $a$'s less than 50 combined, combined exponents for $2^n-1$, $3^n-2^n$, $4^n-3^n$, $5^n-4^n$, and so on up to $50^n-49^n$. This sequence:  https://oeis.org/A222119 may help. (Only focus on the primes for where $k$ < $50$.)